# UpdateListItems won't let you reset field value to empty?

Tags: ajax, web-services, 2007

I've recently discovered that the Lists.asmx ignores your attempts to reset a field's value to empty string or null with Lists.UpdateListItems. Not a very well documented limitation discovered by trial and error.

Can someone advise on the possibility to reset field values using FP RPC / OWSAPI from AJAXy pages? Or am I missing something in the OOTB web service functionality / CAML syntax? I mean without deploying a custom Web Service just for that little generic task?

Comment: I tried <Field></Field> and for lookups <Field>0;#</Field> and <Field>;#</Field>. To no avail. Both via AJAX calls and via u2u CAML Query Builder.
I'm now looking into owsvsvr.dll calls which may be what DataView WebPart and SPD do.

Comment: Have you tried using a variable set to null or empty?

Comment: Where exactly? I'm not aware of a way to reference null-valued client side variables via SOAP XML-based request other than just <Field Name='' />

Comment: Well I think I'd like to revive this discussion. Let's start a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a test with SPServices where I set a **Single line of text** column to an empty string (""), which seemed to work just fine. This was with WSS 3.0 (the simplest test case, IMO).

```
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    debug:true,
    listName: "Sales Opportunities",
    ID: 5,
    valuepairs: [["StateID", ""]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      alert(xData.responseText);
    }
  });
```

This generates the call:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>Sales Opportunities</listName>
      <updates>
        <Batch OnError="Continue">
          <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
            <Field Name="StateID"></Field>
            <Field Name="ID">5</Field>
          </Method>
        </Batch>
      </updates>
    </UpdateListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

EDIT:

I just did the same thing for a **Lookup** column and a **Person or Group** column. The valuepairs line is:

```
valuepairs: [["State", ""], ["Sales_x0020_Rep", ""]],
```

Both columns were "emptied".

Comment: OK, how about a lookup field?

Comment: +1, just sending `<Field Name="LookupField"></Field>` seems to work fine.

Comment: Yay! I got 50 points. I'll go buy something with them right away. ;+)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, had to resort to writing a custom web service that also makes great bandwidth savings.

Comment: But that's not the definitive answer to my own inquiry whether or not there IS a way to reset a field value to null.